# Facebook URL like for SubPages

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Let's say
I have a website: www.example.com

It's a platform where user can create some events. So they create events like: www.example.com/event1
www.example.com/event2

I also have a facebook app: Example
It does basic functions like LogIn with FB and all.

I created a FACEBOOK LIKE BUTTON for my page using Example App.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>EXAMPLE WEBSITE</title>

    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.examplewebsite.com" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Example Website" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.examplewebiste.com/image.jpg" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id"    content="MY_APP_ID">

</head>
<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-like" 
        data-href=<?php echo $CURRENTURL ?> 
        data-layout="standard" 
        data-action="like" 
        data-show-faces="true">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now it shows different number of likes in example.com/event1 and example.com/event2

What I want to ask is that if I do 
    https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.example.com
will it show sum of likes in all pages like /event1 and /event2 and so on..?

Answer (score 0):

**No** it will not. Each URL represent an object in the Graph and likes attached to that object only.